# Using Ember's Handlebars #each helper within a block helper that slices an array into chunks

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to slice an `ArrayController`'s `content` into chunks (for presentational purposes). Within each chunk I want to iterate over the items in order to render everything properly.

I've tried accomplishing this by writing a `partition` Handlebars block helper, which seems to work. However, when I try to loop over the content of each chunk, `each` throws the following error: `"Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed [object Object]"`

**helpers.js**

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('partition', function(path, options){
  path = path === '' ? 'this' : path;
  var arr = [];
  var data = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, path, options).content;
  var ret = '';
  while(data.length){
    arr.push(data.splice(0, options.hash.size || 2));
  }
  for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){
    ret = ret + options.fn(arr[i]);
  };
  return ret;
});
```

**template.hbs**

```
<h2>Your photos</h2>
{{#partition controller.photos size=2}}
  <div class="slide">
    {{#each this}}
      {{this.title}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
  <br/><br/><br/>
{{/partition}}
```

`this` within the `#partition` is the correctly sized array.

How can I get this to work? Where is `each` getting its content from?

gist can be found here: https://gist.github.com/frekw/2d3627039b42891a0b0a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved your issue, see [this JSBin for a demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iManeTa/1/edit).

- In the helper I create a new `Ember.Object` containing the partitioned collection. This object is passed as the context to `options.fn()`.
- I added a `with` helper within the block to set the context for the `each` block.

```
{{#partition photos size=2}}
  <div class="slide">
    {{#with collection}}
      {{#each}}
        {{title}}
      {{/each}}
    {{/with}}
  </div>
  <br/><br/><br/>
{{/partition}}
```

The helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper("partition", function(collection, options){

  var size = options.hash.size || 2;

  while(collection.length > 0)
  {
    var oc = Ember.Object.create({
      collection: collection.splice(0, size)
    });
    options.fn(oc);
  }

});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so much!

I'm still not fully sure why creating a new `Ember.Object` worked instead of just iterating over an array. My best guess is that it has something to do with `#each`'s implementation details. Or why `#with` is needed for the `#each` to work. But I guess my understanding of Ember will get there in time :)

Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, wrapping my original solution in `#with` seems to work as well. I think I need to read up upon scoping in Ember's Handlebars helpers.

Comment: @frekw You're welcome. Yeah Ember Handlebars helpers are very badly documented. I too was thinking that I should just be able to pass an array. I hope they improve this in the future.